# How I can recive colored result from Replace Function?

Tags: c#-4.0

How I can recive colored result from Replace Function?

```
Regex.Replace("My Document", "My", ?);
```

EDITED:

I soleved it:

```
 if (richTextBox1.Find("ab") > 0)
    {
     richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
```

Comment: What does a colored result mean?

Comment: Strings in programming don't have inherent color; your path would be something like: Retrieve regex match, determine string index/length of your search result, and then command a rich text box to display that string section in a certain color. So, it would be a pretty manual process.

Answer (score 0):

(Parts) in strings don't have an inherent color. A string is only a sequence of characters. Some terminals however use "escape characters" that are interpreted as meta-data on how to typeset parts of the string.

For instance the linux shell uses data like `"\033[31mHello\e[0m World"` to highlight Hello in red. But there are always terminals that will not recognize such directives.

---

Some control components (i.e. the `RichtTextBox`) use such directives as well and provide transparent methods to insert directives.